# Disable button before work in background Angular?

Tags: angular

Our angular app has a component-heavy page to display to the user. One of the repeating component is  a list of cards that can be collapsed (showing less details) or expanded (showing more).

To keep track of what the user expands/collapses, we have an array of boolean. If array[2] = true, then the third card is open.

We implemented a button to expand/collapse all, but this page can display many cards, the UI can be unresponsive and the user does not know that, leading to more clicks, leading to more unresponsiveness.

We have tried this (`isExpanding is linked to the button [isDisabled]`);

```
expandAll(display: boolean) {
    this.isExpanding = true;
    this.expandedCards = this.expandedCards.map(() => true);
    this.isExpanding = false;
}
```

But this did not work. So we tried this;

```
expandAll(display: boolean) {
    this.isExpanding = true;
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.expandedCards = this.expandedCards.map(() => true);
        this.isExpanding = false;
        this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
    }, 0);
}
```

But while this is visually ok (button is disabled while working), it still listens to clicks and will fire the events in a queue-like manner.
We are looking for a way to completely ignore any click while the UI is not refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

> .html

```
<button type="button" [disabled]="clicked" (click)="expandAll(); clicked = true;">
  <samp *ngIf="!clicked"> More... </samp>
  <samp *ngIf="clicked"> Loading </samp>
</button>
```

> .ts

```
clicked = false;

expandAll() {

 this.expandedCards = this.expandedCards.map(() => true);

// Can add then when cempelte to set clicked = false

//Test work
// setTimeout(() => {
    //  this.clicked = false;
   // }, 20000);

}
```

Test
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xpmwqg

Hope this helps.